# Odd Bootstrap Dropdown and Button behavior in Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I am creating a navbar menu with bootstrap 3. I have a dropdown menu populated with buttons. The display functions in Chrome, but not in Firefox. In FF the border of the menu cuts into the buttons, rather than around it.

I have found an odd "hack" to get the correct display in Firefox. Adding an a regular link element that has about as much text as the button elements causes it to  display correctly.

Site with error. Lines 19-29. (corresponds to the number 3 next to the acid element) http://bootply.com/101568

Hack: line 21 on http://bootply.com/101564

Is there a better way to get the display to appear correctly on firefox, and if so, what is it?

Comment: 1. what is the question here? 2. I wouldn't call that a "Hack". You are supposed to use links inside drop-downs, not buttons...you are just doing it wrong in the first example...

Comment: 1.Edited to show question
2. feel free to explain that in an answer with sources and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using buttons in drop-downs is not officially supported(as of version 3.0.3). But it sounds like its something they may be adding in the future.

The styles and js for dropdowns use `.dropdown > li > a` as the selector, which is why you get weird and inconsistent results if you don't use links.

[Style input/button tags in dropdowns](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10248)

Quote from mdo(creator of bootstap)....

> Until v4 drops, we cannot change the behavior of the dropdown items, and by that I mean the only way we'd account for this is with required classes on the dropdown links (e.g., .dropdown-item instead of .dropdown > li > a). We could account for this in v3.1 perhaps if we only deprecate the old selectors, but I'm unsure of the trade offs